# Помогите создать шифр одиночной перестановки по ключу на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Только начинаю изучать питон, очень нужна помощь тк. в интернете не особо много информации на эту тему, буду очень признателен

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
(Ключ - пеликан)
(Зашифровать - ТЕРМИНАТОР ПРИБЫВАЕТ СЕДЬМОГО В ПОЛНОЧЬ)
(Результат - ГНВЕП ЛТООА ДРНЕВ ТЕЬИО РПОТМ БЧМОР СОЫЬИ)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А какой алгоритм шифра?

Answer (score 2):

```
def getCipher(origin_key, origin_text):
    clear_text = ''.join(origin_text.split(' ')).lower()
    k = len(clear_text) // len(origin_key)

    cipher = {}
    for index, ch in enumerate(origin_key.lower()):
        if ch in cipher:
            cipher[ch] += clear_text[index * k : index * k + k]
        else:
            cipher[ch] = clear_text[index * k : index * k + k]

    cipher_text = ''.join([''.join([cipher[key][index] for key in sorted(cipher.keys())]) for index in range(k)])
    return ' '.join([cipher_text[index : index + k] for index in range(0, len(cipher_text), k)]).upper()


print(getCipher('ПЕЛИКАН', 'ТЕРМИНАТОР ПРИБЫВАЕТ СЕДЬМОГО В ПОЛНОЧЬ'))
# ГНВЕП ЛТОАА ДРНЕВ ТЕЬИО РПОТМ БЧМОР СОЫЬИ
```