# Помогите реализовать дешифровку шифра одиночной перестановки по ключу

Tags: python, python-3.x, криптография

Написал такую функцию для шифрования методом одиночной перестановки по ключу, но не могу понять как сделать дешифровку полученного зашифрованного сообщения.

```
def getCipher(origin_key, origin_text):
clear_text = ''.join(origin_text.split(' ')).lower()
k = len(clear_text) // len(origin_key)

cipher = {}
for index, ch in enumerate(origin_key.lower()):
    if ch in cipher:
        cipher[ch] += clear_text[index * k : index * k + k]
    else:
        cipher[ch] = clear_text[index * k : index * k + k]

cipher_text = ''.join([''.join([cipher[key][index] for key in sorted(cipher.keys())]) for index in range(k)])
return ' '.join([cipher_text[index : index + k] for index in range(0, len(cipher_text), k)]).upper()


print(getCipher('ПЕЛИКАН', 'ТЕРМИНАТОР ПРИБЫВАЕТ СЕДЬМОГО В ПОЛНОЧЬ'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного изменил [предыдущий ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1021939/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python), который, если помог, стоит **отметить решением**.

```
def encode(keyword, message, normalize=False):
    # True - отбрасывать пробелы при шифровании
    if normalize:
        message = ''.join(message.split())

    rows = len(message) // len(keyword)
    if len(message) % len(keyword) != 0:
        rows += 1

    indexes = sorted([(index, value) for index, value in enumerate(keyword)], key=lambda item: item[1])
    result = ''

    for row in range(rows):
        for index in indexes:
            position = index[0] * rows + row
            if position < len(message):
                result += message[position]
            else:
                result += ' '

    return result


def decode(keyword, cipher):
    rows = len(cipher) // len(keyword)
    if len(cipher) % len(keyword) != 0:
        rows += 1

    indexes = sorted([(index, value) for index, value in enumerate(keyword)], key=lambda item: item[1])
    indexes = sorted([(index, value) for index, value in enumerate(indexes)], key=lambda item: item[1][0])
    result = ''

    for index in indexes:
        for row in range(rows):
            position = index[0] + len(keyword) * row
            if position < len(cipher):
                result += cipher[position]

    return result


key = 'ПЕЛИКАН'
text = 'ТЕРМИНАТОР ПРИБЫВАЕТ СЕДЬМОГО В ПОЛНОЧЬ'

enc = encode(key, text, True)
print('ENCODE:', enc)
dec = decode(key, enc)
print('DECODE:', dec)
print()
enc = encode(key, text)
print('ENCODE:', enc)
dec = decode(key, enc)
print('DECODE:', dec)
```

**Результат**:

```
ENCODE: ГНВЕПЛТОААДРНЕВТЕЬИОРПОТМБЧМОРСОЫЬИ
DECODE: ТЕРМИНАТОРПРИБЫВАЕТСЕДЬМОГОВПОЛНОЧЬ

ENCODE: ВАЕЬРОТ ТТМИЧЕПО ОБЬРОРСГЫ МЛ ЕОВ ИНПД А Н
DECODE: ТЕРМИНАТОР ПРИБЫВАЕТ СЕДЬМОГО В ПОЛНОЧЬ
```